# Why am I still getting package authentication warnings even after disabling validity check on Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude, debian-jessie

I'm still running Debian 8 "Jessy" on my outdated Banana Pi BPI-R1 hardware. But now, when I try to install a package, I get

> `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!`

After running

```
$ apt update                                
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
...
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages                                                                                                                                                                                  
Fetched 168 kB in 26s (6457 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
34 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1668891673
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717
```

it turns out that the Debian keys expired in 2022. Ok, after searching for the issue I found out that there is a workaround by disabling the validity check.

Basically I followed the guideline from https://blog.milliondollarserver.com/2020/06/fix-apt-get-update-error-on-old-debian.html

Unfortunately the workaround does not fix my problem. I still get warnings when I try to "work" with packages:

```
$ apt install dpkg-sig
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] 
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

I verified that the fix has been applied:

```
$ apt-config dump|grep Valid
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

*There are no plans yet to replace the hardware and use a recent Debian... ;-)*

Comment: Why don’t you just add the new key that replaced the expired key. The article you reference was from 2020, which was 2 years, before the key expired. It’s Jessie not “Jessy”. Anyways, running, *sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com 7638D0442B90D010* will add the new key.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598344/debian-8-jessie-keyexpired-1587841717) is probably the better solution though

Comment: You also have to copy your key ring, remove the invalid key, then, use the new key ring instead of copy with the invalid key. Those instructions you followed are incorrect for that reason